# I would like to process and insert merged dataframes into a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance, dictionary

I have dataframes that I would like to process. The problem is as follows.
I have inputs of multiple dataframes that look like this:

```
| name    | painting          | price |
| paul    | mona_lisa         | 10    |
| chani   | avignon           | 14    |
| jessica | internationalblue | 9     |
| thufir  | lastsupper        | 12    |
| jessica | voyager           | 11    |
| chani   | venus             | 7     |
```

another input would be

```
| name    | painting      | price |
| paul    | canneds_oup   | 14    |
| paul    | guernica      | 19    |
| thufir  | bedroom       | 5     |
| thufir  | starynight    | 3     |
```

In the end, I would like a dictionary where every key is the distinct name and every value is a dataframe:

```
dic = {'paul' : | painting    | price | , 'chani' : ... , 'jessica' ......}
                | mona _lisa  | 10    |
                | canned_soup | 14    |
                | guernica    | 19    |
```

I provide the code to generate the input dataframes and output dictionary below. NOTE: I cannot concatenate the dataframes, as they are much to long. I am open to any processing of the dataframes that end up at the end result, and I suspect this will entail use of dictionaries but I have not yet been able to figure it out. I'll update this post if I figure it out.

```
input1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['name','painting','price'], data =[['paul', 'mona_lisa', 10],['chani','avignon',14],['jessica','internationablue',9],\
                                                             ['thufir','lastsupper',12],['chani','voyager',11],['jessica','venus',7]])
input2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['name','painting','price'], data =[['paul', 'cannedsoup', 14],['paul','guernica',19],['thufir','bedroom',5],\
                                                             ['thufir','starynight',3]])


concatenated_dictionary = {'paul' : pd.DataFrame(columns=['painting','price'], data = [['mona_lisa', 10],[ 'cannedsoup', 14],['guernica',19]]),
        'chani' : pd.DataFrame(columns=['painting','price'], data = [['avignon',14],['voyager',11]]),
    'jessica' : pd.DataFrame(columns=['painting','price'], data = [['internationablue',9],['venus',7]]),
'thufir' : pd.DataFrame(columns=['painting','price'], data = [['lastsupper',12],['bedroom',5],['starynight',3]])
      }
```

I've done it the brute force way : first by groupby name, then by either creating a dictionary entry for that name or appending to a list at that name. Here is the code:

```
dfs = [v for k, v in temp.groupby('name')]

for b in dfs:
    key = b['name'].iloc[0]
    try:
        iddic[key].append(b)
    except:
        iddic[key] = [b]
```

and then i concatenate the list of dataframes in a seperate loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can do simple `pd.concat`/`.groupby` followed by `dict()`:

```py
out = dict(
    (i, d[["painting", "price"]])
    for i, d in pd.concat([input1, input2]).groupby("name")
)
print(out)
```

Comment: hello mate - your solution works, (and thats what i want to do to!), but as i wrote, I cant concat the dataframes, they are too big

Comment: @user22191883 But If they are too big, where do you want to hold the final dictionary?

Comment: so like, the final dictionary would have a very large amount of keys, but each value would not be very large - does that make sense?